# Eclipse doesn't run

Tags: eclipse, java

When I run Eclipse it alerts Couldn't find a Java Virtual Machine. OS I use is Windows XP. Java upgrated. Is it can be due to wrong installation of JDK? I installed it in drive D, not C. JDK also the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Eclipse directory and in the *eclipse.ini* file remove the memory value

**Before**

```
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
```

**After**

```
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
```

Now Eclipse is runned without an error

Answer (score 1):

In the eclipse.ini file, located in the root directory of eclipse, put the next param:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javaw.exe
```

Using your java instalation path instead of `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03`

Comment: It didn't help. "Failed to create Java Virtual Machine"

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem so i just copied the jre sub-folder from my java main folder (C:\program files\java....)  and pasted it in the eclipse folder (find where you installed yours) and eclipse is running so well.... Hope it helps you. Later..

Comment: This might work, but you shouldn't have to copy the JVM to every place. Setting the right environment variables will allow the JVM to be found. It is analogous to PATH: one does not copy a program to each place one needs to use it.